# Error trying to connect to a FTP from a sco server

Tags: ftp, cron

i need to implement a script the can send file from a server A with (sco unix) and server b with ubuntu 8.04.

i have no idea how to accomplish this task.

i will really appreciate any help
I have read so far that I have to make an .netrc file in the home directory, but I don’t know what I have to put inside this file
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was easier what i thought, what I did was

**Server A  (sco Operating System)**

Create a system user call test

Then inside of the test folder (test/) I create a file call .netrc

vi .netrc

Machine xxx.xxx.xx.x

User test

Password test

**Server B (Ubuntu)**

Create a ftp account call test

And this is it. Now I can write an script to login via ftp from server A to Server B without any user interference